# Regex to allow only alphabetical characters, hyphens, apostrophes and period

Tags: regex

I got a reference from the link: [Javascript validation to allow only Alpha characters, hyphen (-), dot (.), apostrophe ('), and space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735097/javascript-validation-to-allow-only-alpha-characters-hyphen-dot-apost)

And I have exactly the same requirement. But with the regex `/^[a-zA-Z '.-]+$/` following strings are also accepted:

1. ...
2. tavish. ( I need special character only for the middle name)

So I tried following regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z]*[ '.-][a-zA-Z]+$
```

but it is also failing. I have tried on [Regex100](https://regex101.com) as well but no success. Please let meknow how can I achieve this?

Comment: Try this `^[a-zA-Z](?:[ '.\-a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `*` quantifier to make letters be at beginning and consider them at end:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?:[ '.\-a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])?$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/k6u3yM/1)

Comment: Thanks! Working fine. Except one senario: test...test. It should allow only one special character in between.

Comment: Then use this `^[a-zA-Z](?:[ '.\-a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z])*$`

Comment: The regex is allowing me pass string: 'tavish.agg1s'. But it is not a valid string.

Comment: ohh yes. It is not working with angular pattern validators. :|

Comment: Please make a fiddle.